# Schematizing the variance in R as a moment of inertia

Tags: r, graphics

The variance of a distribution has a physical interpretation as a moment of inertia around the mean of the distribution. I'd like to represent the variance in R by a schema as the one shown below: like an open ellipse with an arrow, which is a common way to represent a moment of inertia. Do you have some suggestion to do this job conveniently ? I want to be able to add this ellipse to a base graphic, by specifying the coordinates of the center and the lengths of the two "radius" (and optionally the length of the "break").

[image]

Comment: Does this need to be a programming solution? Can't you export a figure and add a (nice looking) arrow in Inkscape or some other software for vector or raster data?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, I need a programming solution, because I want to add this schema to many R graphics (moreover this is for a reproducible report generated by knitr).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Which graphics package are you using for plotting? This is rather simple with 'grid' graphics, but many other packages can be quite resistant to custom changes like this.

Comment: @Dinre I'd like "base" graphics. Do you mean the `grid.curve()` function ? I have taken a look at the documentation and it seems quite complicated.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Actually, there are a plethora of approaches in 'grid' that you could use to do this, but the simplest would be to use an ellipse and "break" it with a small background-colored square.  Add a simple triangle and you have your arrow.  But if you really want to use 'base' functions, perhaps the 'addLogo' function would be best.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Are all of your graphs like this going to be using the same sort of data?  If so, perhaps you could share a data sample and ask for help making a plotting function wrapper.  Then, you wouldn't have to particularly learn 'pixmap' or 'grid' functions yourself.  This may not work for your case, but I thought I'd put the idea out there.

Comment: @Dinre Yes, I think too that the ellipse with the break should be nice. Actually I mainly want to have control on the position and the size, there's no important need to have control on the angle of the arrow for instance. I don't understand your question about my "data", I just want this schema that I could put on any graphic.

Comment: OK, I'm confused.  The ellipse makes me think you're implying that the data is actually a 3D, rotationally symmetric, peak.  If that's what you mean, why not create a 3D grid of data and plot that?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm afraid what your asking for doesn't make much sense from a plotting perspective. Different types of data and plots (time-measurement data on control chart, count data on Pareto chart, vector movement data on a wind chart, x-y-z data on a geo-plot, etc.) will require different approaches. Saying you "want this schema that I could put on any graphic" doesn't give any direction on how to answer your question.

Comment: @Dinre This is not what I meant. My english is limited, sorry. I just meant that I want a function which plots this schema in my graphic window when I specifiy the center of the ellipse and a scaling factor.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  I have edited my post to add a picture. I just want to reproduce such a picture. Plotting the distribution is not difficult, so I just want something to plot the open ellipse with the arrow.

Comment: Maybe this could help, I will look at this later: http://kbroman.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/curved-arrows-in-r/

Comment: @Dinre I have just edited my post to add an attempt. Is it more clear now ? I don't understand your comments: this is like I'd ask "how to draw a circle in R?" and then you ask me some questions about my data. My problem has nothing to do with data.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes, that is clearer.  I ask about your data, because custom graphics are difficult when using 'base' plotting functions. If you could describe your data, someone could write a function for you that created the entire graphic using a more flexible package, like 'grid'.  Then, the solution would be quite simple to write, and you wouldn't have to learn to use 'grid' yourself.

Comment: @Dinre Again, **there's no data in my problem**. Or I don't understand what you mean by "data". But anyway I just want to be able to add such a plot to a graphic, by specifying the coordinates of the center and the two "radius".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code for my solution:

```
inertia <- function(x0=0, y0=0, a, b, r=1/5, l=0.25, d=3, s=0, w=NULL, cols="black", npoints=101, ...){
  if(length(cols==1)) cols <- rep(cols,3)
  # ellipse:
  f <- function(x) sqrt(round(b^2*(1-(x-x0)^2/a^2),14)) 
  curve(y0 + f(x), from=x0-a, to=x0-a*r, add=TRUE, n=npoints, col=cols[1], ...)
  curve(y0 + f(x), from=x0+a*r, to=x0+a, add=TRUE, n=npoints, col=cols[2], ...)
  curve(y0 - f(x), from=x0-a, to=x0+a, add=TRUE, n=npoints, col=cols[3], ...)
  # arrow:
  segments(x0-s, y0-b, x0-l, y0-b+l/d, col=cols[3], ...)
  segments(x0-s, y0-b, x0-l, y0-b-l/d, col=cols[3], ...)
  if(!is.null(w)){
    segments(x0-s+w, y0-b, x0-l, y0-b+l/d, col=cols[3], ...)
    segments(x0-s+w, y0-b, x0-l, y0-b-l/d, col=cols[3], ...)
  }
}
```

[image]

See http://stla.overblog.com/schematizing-the-variance-as-a-moment-of-inertia for explanations.